# How to get machine id using Javascript and Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to locate computer machine id using Javascript in client side and back-end using Node. If I use `var machineId = require("ee-machine-id");` this module gives me path error.

```
fs.readdirSync('./controllers').forEach(function(file) {
  if (file.substr(-3) == '.js') {
    route = require('./controllers/' + file);
    var BASE = {
      APP: app,
      FS: fs,
      urlEncodedParser: urlEncodedParser,
      utils: utils,
      request: request,
      io: io,
      async: async,
      trim: trim,
      upload: upload,
      FormData: FormData,
      Download: Download,
      http: http,
      os: os,
      machineId: machineId
    };
    route.controller(BASE);
  }
});
```

Error:

> ```
> return binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
>                  ^
> ```
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/www/html/nodeproject/helloworld/index'

How can I use this npm module and how do I get the machine id using Javascript so that I can match the value either front end and backend have same machine id.

Comment: What does the code you have shown have to do with the error?

Comment: BASE.machineId.get( function( id ){
 console.log( id ); // 5ccbe155d5440cd06e3664c0ae3e811e
} );

Comment: Can you please share your folder structure?

Comment: @TusharArora: helloworld is the main folder inside that: controllers, node_modules,views,index.js like that

Comment: It has nothing to do with ee-machine-id module. You can try to run your node program with sudo or try to move the folder to another location and run it again.